# How to sort a Hashmap<String, List<String>> according to the elements on the list? Java 8

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, java-stream

I'm trying to sort this in natural order byKey and byValue using lambda expression and Stream Pipe line Java 8:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
```

So, the first part (sorting by natural order) is easy but I am having difficulty with the second part.

The sort should be done by the elements of the list`(List<String>)` and the result looks like:

```
input:
{E, [G,B,H]}
{C, [E,A,B]}
{A, [M,D,C]}

output:
{A, [C,D,M]}
{C, [A,B,E]}
{E, [B,G,H]}
```

The first part of the sort byKey is like:

```
result.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).forEach(e -> {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue() );
        });
```

But as I mentioned before I don't know how exactly do the next step:

```
result.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()
                    .thenComparing((e1,e2) -> e1.getValue().stream().sorted((s1,s2) -> s1.compareTo(s2)))
                        )
            .forEach(e -> {
                System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue() );
            });
```

This lambda expression gave me some compile errors.
Also could you add sources to read about?

Comment: Are you trying to modify the original `Map` to sort its values, or keep it the same and only iterate through the values in sorted order? Do you _always_ want to use the `Map` in key order? There are other `Map` implementations that store the keys in order, which could be more efficient than sorting them each time they are iterated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot depend on the keys to remain in sorted order in the resulting map since maps are inherently unordered.  It may appear to work but it depends on the `hashCodes` of the keys and other map factors. But for larger maps you cannot depend on it.  To solve this you can specify a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) which maintains a sorted order for the keys as then resultant map and use `streams` to sort the lists.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = Map.of("E", List.of("G", "B", "H"), "C",
        List.of("E", "A", "B"), "A", List.of("M", "D", "C"));

Map<String, List<String>> result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                e -> e.getValue().stream().sorted().toList(),
                (a,b)->a, // merge function here, not used but required
                TreeMap::new));

result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
A=[C, D, M]
C=[A, B, E]
E=[B, G, H]
```

An alternative to the above is to sort the `Entry` based on the key and the specify a `LinkedHashMap`.  LinkedHashMaps retain their insertion order. Everything else is the same as above.

```
Map<String, List<String>> result2 = map.entrySet().stream()
.sorted(Entry.comparingByKey())
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
        e -> e.getValue().stream().sorted().toList(),
        (a,b)->a,   // merge function here, not used but required
        LinkedHashMap::new));
```